# javascript dropdown condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following dropdown. Client wants to form throw an error if the value fail is selected. I told him easy solution is to remove the fail from the menu :) That way only option is Pass and the problem is solved:) Not really. He still wants both options and if Fail selected he wants to see the required error may be a text saying you need to select Pass.

```
               <div class="section colm colm6">
                  <label class="field select">
                      <select id="cond" name="Cond" required>
                           <option value=''>Condition</option>
                           <option value='Pass' >Pass</option>
                           <option value='Fail' >Fail</option>
                        </select>
                          <i class="arrow double"></i>                             
                  </label>
               </div>
```

I need to do the error check as soon as the file is selected rather than until the whole form is submitted. I have another 2 fail and pass dropdowns and 2 yes and no dropdowns that I need to do the same thing. If I get one working I should be able to the others (I hope)

I am guessing that I need to create a some sort of function similar to

```
  function checkCategory(){
        if(document.getElementById('cond').value === 'Fail') {
           alert("Client says you need to enter Pass");
   return false;
   }
  }
```

and may be use an onselect ( I am not sure how to call it ) use onselect="javascript:checkCategory();"

I am pretty much stuck at this point. Your help is much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: why you use plain js instead of jquery?

Comment: There is no `onselect` it should be `onchange`;

Comment: now by "Throw an error" do you mean alert the client that they've selected an invalid value; or do you mean throw an actual error in javascript. Because those are two different things.

Comment: Thanks itzmukeshy7 that is oncahnge is the function I needed. Uzaif fancy JS works too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easy to do this using jquery, just use its `.change()` event handler as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $('#cond').change(function() {
    if(this.value === 'Fail') {
        alert('Please Select Pass');
    }
  })
})
```

This will solve your problem. Check this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/9d3dcd07/

You can also do this in javascript by using an onchange event handler in your select menu as:

```
<script>

function checkCategory() {
    if(document.getElementById('cond').value === 'Fail') {
    alert('Please Select Pass');
  }
  return false;
}

</script>
<div class="section colm colm6">
    <label class="field select">
        <select id="cond" name="Cond" onchange = "checkCategory()"required>
             <option value=''>Condition</option>
             <option value='Pass' >Pass</option>
             <option value='Fail' >Fail</option>
          </select>
            <i class="arrow double"></i>                             
    </label>
 </div>
```

See a working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/9d3dcd07/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```js
$(function(){
  $("select#cond").on("change", function(){
    if(this.value == "Fail"){
      alert("Client says you need to enter Pass.")
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section colm colm6">
  <label class="field select">
    <select id="cond" name="Cond" required>
      <option value=''>Condition</option>
      <option value='Pass' >Pass</option>
      <option value='Fail' >Fail</option>
    </select>
    <i class="arrow double"></i>                             
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are almost there in the code ,

You need to add onChange Event to the select element

```
  <div class="section colm colm6">
              <label class="field select">
                  <select id="cond" name="Cond" required onChange="checkCategory()">
                       <option value=''>Condition</option>
                       <option value='Pass' >Pass</option>
                       <option value='Fail' >Fail</option>
                    </select>
                      <i class="arrow double"></i>                             
              </label>
           </div>
```